# C++ - Determine whether given string has only Furigana Characters

Tags: c++, utf-8, internationalization, ruby-characters

Is there any existing C++ function to determine given string has only [furigana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furigana) characters?

Comment: Seems like a pretty specialized function - I'd expect no such thing. I'm not even sure there is an easy way to "check" if it is such or not.

Comment: Thanks Joachim Pileborg & Mats Petersson.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Furigana is a kind of text annotation, but the characters used for the annotation are not special characters, they are normal hiragana or katakana. So "only furigana characters" doesn't make sense, unless you mean a string consisting entirely of hiragana and katakana.

Answer (score 0):

Furigana is about presentation, it does not exist "as is" in plain text (in C++ strings).
This is like asking for a C++ function to detect bold characters.

Now, if you say "the string contains HTML tagged text", then you can parse the HTML tags and identify the furigana part. (http://www.w3.org/International/articles/ruby/)